# Conditional probability percentage problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

[Hypothetical Numerical Problem] In a city far far away, on Valentine's day, many people celebrate by having dinner in a nice restaurant. Approximately, 30% of women and 20% of men will have such a Valentine's day dinner. 40% of women who go to such a nice dinner will also prepare a gift and 90% of men will prepare a gift. What proportion of this city's women are who go to Valentine's day dinner without a gift?

I have been trying to understand this question but unable to get it. what i understand is that 50% is the sample space S. I think i need to find the conditional probability of women given without gifts. probability of without gift will be calculated by doing 1-P(gifts). I am really lost on this problem. Please help me better understand it.
Ps: The answer to this question is 18%

Comment: The wording of the question is less than clear.  One possible interpretation is that "40% of women who go to such a nice dinner will also prepare a gift" so "60% of women who go to Valentine's day dinner go without a gift", but another would take account of the possibility of being given a gift

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, really appreciated. Basically this is an assignment question on one of the edx stats course. I agree with you about confused nature of question. I failed on solving this question, so really want to understand  it now. Answer to this question is 18%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a super clear and easy question. 30% of city's women go to the party, and 40% of these women who are going there have prepared a gift as well. So 100%-40% of 30% of women of the city are going there without preparing any gift. 60% of 30% is $$0.6\times 0.3=0.18$$ which means 18%.

The information about men is just an extra information which is not going to be used in this question.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Really appreciated